# Kubernetes Gateway API request chaining

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, api-gateway

is it possible to chain requests through multiple backends with the new https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/ ?

The idea is to have a flow depending on the response headers of each service ie:

Request -> Gateway -> [ first backend service "Custom forward Header" -> second backend service -> "Custom forward Header" -> x service ] -> Response

Comment: trying to understand the use case, in your case why wouldn't you simply send the request from the first backend service to the second backend service by caliing the second backend service? I feel like I'm missing something

Comment: Ie if I want to render a pdf or any action with the responses y could send the request from the client with actions to be make with the response , the response is added with headers that indicates the actions to be made and I want to configure routing based on this actions to forward the request in this case render a pdf , this allows me to separate logic in services and don’t have logic attached to the main service that process the original request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of the [Kubernetes Gateway API](https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/), it is generally designed to manage *inbound* request traffic effectively through various kinds of Gateways, such as HTTPRoute, TCPRoute, etc.

This question is more about managing east/west traffic — that is, the traffic flowing between services inside the same Kubernetes cluster.

This should be possible with a service mesh: Leveraging a service mesh such as [Istio](https://istio.io/) or [Linkerd](https://linkerd.io/) can provide more sophisticated routing capabilities, including conditional routing based on headers.
That is part of the [GAMMA initiative](https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/concepts/gamma/), which is still very much a work in progress.

In the meantime, "[The Future of API Gateways on Kubernetes](https://wso2.com/library/blogs/the-future-of-api-gateways-on-kubernetes/)" (Aug. 2023) from [Pubudu Gunatilaka](https://twitter.com/pubuduspace) (Senior Technical Lead @ WSO2) points to:

> In 2022, [Matt Klein](https://twitter.com/mattklein123), the creator of Envoy, introduced a new project called [**Envoy Gateway**](https://gateway.envoyproxy.io/), specifically targeting API gateways.
> Envoy already had the necessary components for building an API gateway, including a proxy layer; a configurable filter architecture for network traffic filtering, routing, and processing; and xDS APIs for transmitting data to Envoy proxies.
> The open source Envoy Gateway project adds a management layer to handle an Envoy proxy as a standalone gateway or as a Kubernetes-managed API gateway.

You do not need an Envoy Gateway, but, as [Debasree Panda](https://imesh.ai/about-us.html) confirms in "[What is Envoy Gateway, and why is it required for Kubernetes?](https://imesh.ai/blog/what-is-envoy-gateway/)":

> [Envoy proxy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/), the data plane of Istio service mesh, is used for handling east-west traffic ( service-to-service communication within a data center)

So you should be able to implement your use case, using for instance [LUA filter / `headers()`](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.27.0/configuration/http/http_filters/lua_filter.html#headers).